# "Private Bytes" doesn't reflect it. How to find exact memory allocated by process?

Tags: c++, windows, memory, memory-management

Here is sample piece of C++ code compiled and run using VS2010 on Windows XP.

It prints "private bytes" before and after allocation.

```
void PrintPrivateBytes()
{
    HANDLE current_process;
    PROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS_EX pmc;

    current_process = GetCurrentProcess();

    if (!GetProcessMemoryInfo(current_process, (PPROCESS_MEMORY_COUNTERS)&pmc, sizeof(pmc)))
    {
        std::cout << "\nGetProcessMemoryInfo failed" ;
        return;
    }

    std::cout << "\nProcess private bytes: " << pmc.PrivateUsage/1024 << " KB"; 
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    // Code demonstrating private bytes doesn't change
    std::cout << "\n\nBefore allocating memory" ;
    PrintPrivateBytes();

    char* charptr = new char[8192];
    std::cout << "\n\nAfter allocating 8 KB memory" ;
    PrintPrivateBytes();

    delete[] charptr;
    std::cout << "\n\nAfter deleting memory" ;
    PrintPrivateBytes();

    int RetVal = _heapmin();
    std::cout << "\n\nAfter calling _heapmin" ;
    PrintPrivateBytes();

    return 0;
}
```

Here is output:

> Before allocating memory
>
> Process private bytes: 416 KB
>
> After allocating memory
>
> Process private bytes: 428 KB
>
> After deleting memory
>
> Process private bytes: 428 KB
>
> After calling _heapmin
>
> Process private bytes: 428 KB

It indicates "private bytes" doesn't reflect exact memory usage of process.

Which Windows API/structure will help finding **exact** memory usage of process ?
(Working set is also of no use. It just reflect much how physical memory is being used)

Comment: What's the return value of _heapmin?

Comment: @Werner: It returns 0

Comment: You shouldn't expect that the freed memory in a process is immediately returned to the OS. The behavior you see is normal.

Comment: Assuming you're talking about total amount of committed memory, you could work this out using [VirtualQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366902(v=vs.85).aspx).  Note also that the source code for the Visual Studio C runtime is available, so you could check to see exactly how _heapmin is implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution of checking the private bytes is correct, only your assumption about _heapmin is wrong.

_heapmin does not work as documented. _heapmin is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fc7etheh.aspx) as "Releases unused heap memory to the operating system."

The implementation (see "\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\heapmin.c") is

```
int __cdecl _heapmin(void)
{
        if ( HeapCompact( _crtheap, 0 ) == 0 ) {
            return -1;
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
}
```

HeapCompact is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to normally do quite nothing despite returning the size of the largest free block in the heap. It only does some extra stuff if a special global (debug purpose) flag is used.

Comment: I see. But the question is how to find exact memory acquired by process? If there is no way, it's tough to say if process has memory leaks or not.

Comment: @Andrew What I meant to say: your solution reading the private bytes is not necessarily wrong just because of the observations you did.

Comment: @Andrew _heapwalk et. al.  Note this isn't what your question asked; the runtime is part of the process, so its heap is "memory acquired by the process" even if it isn't "memory acquired by my code".