# Multithreaded application crashes with errors R6016 or 0xC0000005 at high memory usage

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, memory-management

This is multi-threaded console based application being developed in C++ using MSVC2010 on Windows XP. The application consumes high amount of memory. But when memory usage reaches around 2GB (Windows 32bit memory limit) it abruptly crashes at random places with either of these errors:

> 1. R6016- not enough space for thread data
> 2. 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x02030000

Accompanied to this, there is also a string appears on console "runtime error" many many times. But not sure from where is it coming (My code does not print it).

Unfortunately there are no definitive stack traces or locations available where it crashes. It just crashes anywhere especially when memory usage goes around 2GB.
I would expect CRT to return error or failure when it cannot allocate memory. In that case I've made sure the application would run smooth. But why on this earth does it
display message boxes with these errors which led to quit the application.

I am struggling for many days on this and its really unbearable now. I tried:

1) To know the location of crash in code through debugger. But it just crashes anywhere. For e.g. Mostly at new memory allocation calls similar to:

`char* ptr = new (std::nothrow) char[1024];`

As we can see there is no reason for any application to *crash* here.

2) To narrow down the code path to find exact scenario under which it crashes: I couldn't succeeded in this also.

As a workaround I thought to not to touch memory usage of my application to 2GB.
But then a question came to my mind, "What is the guarantee that it will not crash even at low memory usage. It could be just matter of time?"

Also, there is no definitive way to know in advance [how much exact memory is available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402797/private-bytes-doesnt-reflect-it-how-to-find-exact-memory-allocated-by-proces) to allocate.

I am really exhausted out with this bug and desperately need help/guidance.

**UPDATE:**

I narrowed down that this is problem with `QueueUserWorkItem` (Windows function that queues a work item to a worker thread in the thread pool). When the call is made under no memory situation, it causes memory allocations inside thread to fail with "runtime error" Unfortunately, I am unable give here sample code reproducing this crash, because I call that function through a third party library and it is very difficult to extract code out of it for demo.

But to explain, I call the function (with flag `WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION`) and when it finishes it invokes the callback from where I call it again (so that it could process next work item).

As a workaround I am trying to put check on memory usage of the application ("Private Bytes") and not letting it to touch 2GB. Hopefully it should work.

Comment: I guess you mean `new(std::nothrow) char[1024]`? Also, I guess you are aware of the fact that for 32 Bit Windows XP the default limit that an application may use is 2GB (keyword `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`)? Because it crashes randomly, I'd say that some `new` operator in some library (not in your own code) causes a `bad_alloc` which you do not catch, or which the library ignores silently (and thus causes an access violation).

Comment: `(Windows 32bit memory limit)` It really is not the memory limit but the default user address space limit unless you use the /LARGEADDRESSAWARE linker setting and boot with the /3GB switch in boot.ini.

Comment: Use the debugger to stop when the application crashes (i think msvc even does that by default for access violations) and show us the stacktrace?

Comment: @Voo: The debugger trace is of not much use. Coz most of the time it shows landed up in operating system DLL which doesn't have source (And there is no link it shows to app sources)

Comment: @Andrew oh source level debugging is so quaint anyhow ;) looking at the assembly code can tell a great many things and you can get the symbols for the dlls too from MS - although no idea if visual studio can do that - I used windbg in the past.

Comment: It seems clear that the problems are being caused by critically low available address space.  I don't think there's any way to make an application behave reliably under those conditions.  If you can't go 64-bit, you'll just have to avoid allocating too much memory from your code, using a custom allocator if necessary.  You could also consider using one or more memory mapping objects (CreateFileMapping) to minimize the use of address space.

Comment: @Harry, valid points. But this is kind of part of stress testing.  This is a server component. We want it to survive under low memory situation. Ideally `new` or `malloc` returns NULL if they can't allocate memory. So in theory, application should not crash. We letting it to go on allocating and then we finding weakest point.

Comment: @Andrew: I very much doubt that it is practical to make an application survive running out of address space.  If you're determined to try, you'll want to stop using the thread pool for a start; in fact, make sure you don't try to launch any new threads on the fly (i.e., create a fixed pool of threads at application launch and stick to those); you should probably avoid using the C/C++ runtime libraries too, as well as any of the more advanced Windows APIs.  (If you stick to stuff that was available in Windows 2000, or is exported by kernel32, you should be OK.)

Comment: Also, if you can't avoid using the C/C++ runtime, make sure you use _beginthreadex to create the threads, not CreateThread.  That makes sure that the runtime's per-thread storage is allocated straight away and not at an unpredictable later stage.  (This is likely to be be the cause of your R6016 error.)

Answer (score 3):

There are several components:

1. If you're close to the 2GB addressable user space, then you can actually get out of memory issues...
2. The exception that you get isn't a generic "out of memory" problem. Actually it's a "problem when allocating thread local storage".
3. Memory management may rely on thread local storage.

From what I've found (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7b63a615-b906-42dc-87cb-da2638ed03ac/r6016-not-enough-space-for-thread-data?forum=vcgeneral):

> This error can also happen when you create a thread by using CreateThread or any other function which doesn't use _beginthtread/_beginthreadex. To be precise, you won't get this error when the thread is created, you'll get this error later when you try to access some CRT functionality which requires a per thread data structure.

Comment: There are some hints in this thread. Couple of days back I been through the same. But no definitive clue as such. My application doesn't have any direct/indirect calls to TLS etc.

Comment: @Andrew any clever modern memory allocator will use thread local storage to avoid synchronization - so that's definitely a possibility.. How did you check you don't use tls even indirectly? Not aware of anything to check that easily.

Comment: @Voo: Might be you right as it could be happening behind the scene. I am using Windows threadpool so calling QueueUserWorkItem. I just now narrowed down on a piece of code that reproduces this crash. Will update this question with it in some time.