# C++ Builder 6 unresolved _heapmin

Tags: c++, c++builder

I build old project in IDE Borland C++ Builder 6(2002). My code uses function:

```
_heapmin();
```

I find function, she contains in *malloc.h*. C++ Builder find this file (path: (system path)/borland/cbuilder6/include/malloc.h). But, at build appears error:

```
[Linker Error] Unresolved external '__heapmin' referenced from my-file.OBJ
```

Which library i should add to project, or, than replace function *_heapmin()* to C++ Builder 6?
Thanks.

Comment: Why were you using `_heapmin()` to begin with? It releases unused heap memory back to the OS. There is no good reason to EVER call that function directly, even if you are managing your memory allocations correctly. Let the underlying memory manager handle OS memory for you.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, I build project, not writed :) . Also, I found the function device here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24402797/private-bytes-doesnt-reflect-it-how-to-find-exact-memory-allocated-by-proces
And edit code.